# How to force streamed image objects to be cached by Squid Forward Proxy

Tags: cache, squid, http-streaming

I am accessing images stored on storage like AWS S3 or GCS.

I am using a node library called Got to fetch an image, and I stream the response into an image processor.

I am using Got with a tunnel agent so that it uses my Squid Forward Proxy. I am going via Squid, as I want to cache the images so that I don't always need to go all the way to S3 to fetch an image.

My images, however, are not being cached. And every call to fetch the image via Squid results in the following log message:

```
1612789358.530   3100 172.22.0.3 TCP_TUNNEL/200 2296639 CONNECT storage.googleapis.com:80 - HIER_DIRECT/172.217.170.80 -
```

I have added a `refresh_pattern` directive to force caching.

```
refresh_pattern . 0 100% 525600 override-expire override-lastmod ignore-reload ignore-no-cache ignore-no-store reload-into-ims ignore-must-revalidate
```

This should cache everything for a year.

The relevant javascript is this (in case it matters)

```javascript
let stream = await got.stream(sourceUrl, {
  agent: {
    http: tunnel.httpOverHttp({
      proxy: {
        host: "localhost",
        port: "3128",
      },
    }),
  },
});
```

I have no experience with Squid - I am using version 4.x

Can it be, that because I am streaming responses from S3, that Squid can not cache the response once the whole image response has streamed? Or might there be a specific cache directive in my squid.conf file that is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the HTTP CONNECT method through the Squid proxy, which **completely bypasses its cache** and pretty much everything else Squid does.

You should instead connect to it as a normal HTTP proxy, which a quick look at [got's page at npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) indicates should be done with the [hpagent](https://github.com/delvedor/hpagent) package.

Comment: Hi Michael - ok, I see that HTTP CONNECT would bypass the cache. So the solution lies in trying to connect to the proxy so that it doesn't do an HTTP CONNECT to the origin server. I tried swapping out the agent library to the hpagent package - but it still results in a CONNECT method according to the Squid logs I see (which is the same as shown in the question)

Comment: @Joerg At this point you're in programming territory and we can't really help you here. You should try our sister site [so] for help debugging your code.